# Windows 8 metro application title not showing

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

My application's title not showing for some reason. It was working yesterday, I did compare the changes with TFS but nothing really changed that will cause the page title to hide. The page title does appear on design view but not while I am running the application. The page title does appear on other pages so I don't think that it is problem with `LayoutAwarePage`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I have a progress bar on the top of the page which was causing the title to hide. This is little strange though as the progress bar was there to begin with and title was showing up right. But anyways I had to place the progress bar in other grid row for title to work right.

Comment: A lot depends on which layout panel you are using.  You didn't provide code or XAML examples.

Answer (score 0):

try to put both progress bar and your title section in the stack panel.... may be this will work.. and don't change it orientation it is by default vertical